# How to properly solve fibonacci series in javascript using matrices

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve the Fibonacci algorithm using matrices. My target time complexity is an o(logn) instead of an o(n). The return output of the program is not the number for the series but the sixth significant digits. Its why I am returning the remainder of the solution divided by a million.

I have written the code and it runs well but I noticed that for extremely large inputs, I get a NAN(not a number) instead of an output

```
const fib = (n) => {
  let fibMatrix = [[1,1], [1,0]]
  
  if(n == 0){
    return 0;
  }
  
  raiseToPower(fibMatrix, n - 1);
 
  return Math.floor(fibMatrix[0][0] % 1000000)
}

const raiseToPower = (matrix, n) => {
  
  if(n == 0 || n == 1){
    return;
  }
  
  let newMatrix = [[1,1], [1,0]]
  
  raiseToPower(matrix, Math.floor(n / 2))
  
  
  multiplyMatrices(matrix, matrix)
  
  
  
  if(n % 2 !== 0){
    multiplyMatrices(matrix, newMatrix)
  }
  
}

const multiplyMatrices = (matrix, newMatrix) => {
    let x =  matrix[0][0]*newMatrix[0][0] + matrix[0][1]*newMatrix[1][0];
    let y =  matrix[0][0]*newMatrix[0][1] + matrix[0][1]*newMatrix[1][1];
    let z =  matrix[1][0]*newMatrix[0][0] + matrix[1][1]*newMatrix[1][0];
    let w =  matrix[1][0]*newMatrix[0][1] + matrix[1][1]*newMatrix[1][1];
    
    
     
    matrix[0][0] = x;
    matrix[0][1] = y;
    matrix[1][0] = z;
    matrix[1][1] = w;
}

console.log(fib(2000))
```

Thats my code above. Is there anything I could change to actually make this much more performant?

Comment: Is the question about large numbers, or about performance? You should focus on a single issue and add more information about the debugging you have done.

Comment: It's actually about performance. The code works until you get to 1000 and it throws the not a number error which causes the performance test cases to fail.

Comment: You probably get above max possible number and get infinity in this place which causes a NaN. Try using BigInt and if it doesn't work, you should make your calculations on strings.

Comment: About performance, for fibonacci, barely anything beats something like [binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet's_formula)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the error. My numbers were getting larger than the maximum value.

I changed this by instead returning the remainder of my value divided by a million to the matrix and then returning the value from the matrix instead of returning the value and then dividing by a million. The former is efficient and works for any sized inputs.

```
const fib = (n) => {
  let fibMatrix = [[1,1], [1,0]]
  
  if(n == 0){
    return 0;
  }
  
  raiseToPower(fibMatrix, n - 1);
 
  return (fibMatrix[0][0])
}

const raiseToPower = (matrix, n) => {
  
  if(n == 0 || n == 1){
    return;
  }
  
  let newMatrix = [[1,1], [1,0]]
  
  raiseToPower(matrix, Math.floor(n / 2))
  
  
  multiplyMatrices(matrix, matrix)
  
  
  
  if(n % 2 !== 0){
    multiplyMatrices(matrix, newMatrix)
  }
  
}

const multiplyMatrices = (matrix, newMatrix) => {
    let x =  (matrix[0][0]*newMatrix[0][0] + matrix[0][1]*newMatrix[1][0]);
    let y =  (matrix[0][0]*newMatrix[0][1] + matrix[0][1]*newMatrix[1][1]);
    let z =  (matrix[1][0]*newMatrix[0][0] + matrix[1][1]*newMatrix[1][0]);
    let w =  (matrix[1][0]*newMatrix[0][1] + matrix[1][1]*newMatrix[1][1]);
    
    
     
    matrix[0][0] = x % 1000000;
    matrix[0][1] = y % 1000000;
    matrix[1][0] = z % 1000000;
    matrix[1][1] = w % 1000000;
}

console.log(fib(10000))
```